# Drools: issues while loading resources

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor, thread-dump

we recently introduced Drools into our system and soon after some time our servers started misbehaving( crashing or latency increased), We analyzed the Thread dump  and a snippet from the same is as below. Most of the threads from this pool are in BLOCKED STATE.

```
"mainProcessPool-pool-18-thread-1078--ADDADA121312" - Thread t@21148
 java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResources(WebappClassLoader.java:1312)
- waiting to lock <97872c0> (a [Ljava.util.jar.JarFile;) owned by "mainProcessPool-pool-18-thread-1019--ADDADA121312" t@20949
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1040)
at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.getResources(CompositeClassLoader.java:116)
at org.drools.util.ChainedProperties.getResources(ChainedProperties.java:146)
at org.drools.util.ChainedProperties.<init>(ChainedProperties.java:92)
at org.drools.util.ChainedProperties.<init>(ChainedProperties.java:51)
at org.drools.SessionConfiguration.init(SessionConfiguration.java:140)
at org.drools.SessionConfiguration.<init>(SessionConfiguration.java:124)
at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:155)
at com.tnp.drools.configuration.DroolsConfigManager.getStatefullSession(DroolsConfigManager.java:103)
```

Just want to know what what can be the detailed cause for same. What other configuration should I do to prevent such issue.

**====UPDATED WITH JAVA CONFIG**

```
 public class DroolsConfigManager {

private KnowledgeAgentConfiguration knowledgeAgentConfig;
private Properties config;
private String droolCachePath;
private ResourceChangeScannerConfiguration rChangeScannerConfiguration;
private KnowledgeAgent knowledgeAgent;
    public String getDroolCachePath() {
    return this.droolCachePath;
}
public void setDroolCachePath(String droolCachePath) {
    this.droolCachePath = droolCachePath;
}
public KnowledgeAgent getKnowledgeAgent() {
    return this.knowledgeAgent;
}
public void setKnowledgeAgent(KnowledgeAgent knowledgeAgent) {
    this.knowledgeAgent = knowledgeAgent;
}
public ResourceChangeScannerConfiguration getrChangeScannerConfiguration() {
    return this.rChangeScannerConfiguration;
}
public void setrChangeScannerConfiguration(ResourceChangeScannerConfiguration rChangeScannerConfiguration) {
    this.rChangeScannerConfiguration = rChangeScannerConfiguration;
}
public Properties getConfig() {
    return this.config;
}
public void setConfig(Properties config) {
  this.config = config;
    for (Object key : config.keySet()) {
        if (this.knowledgeAgentConfig == null)
            this.knowledgeAgentConfig = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgentConfiguration();
        this.knowledgeAgentConfig.setProperty((String) key, (String) config.get(key));
    }
}

public KnowledgeAgentConfiguration getKnowledgeAgentConfig() {
    return this.knowledgeAgentConfig;
}

public void setKnowledgeAgentConfig(KnowledgeAgentConfiguration knowledgeAgentConfig) {
    this.knowledgeAgentConfig = knowledgeAgentConfig;
}

public void start() {
    if(this.droolCachePath != null){
        System.setProperty("drools.resource.urlcache", this.droolCachePath);
    }
    this.rChangeScannerConfiguration = ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().newResourceChangeScannerConfiguration();
    this.rChangeScannerConfiguration.setProperty(ApplicationConstants.DROOLS_RESOURCE_SCANNER_INTERVAL, this.config.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.DROOLS_RESOURCE_SCANNER_INTERVAL));
    ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().configure(this.rChangeScannerConfiguration);
    ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeNotifierService().start();
    ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().start();
    this.knowledgeAgent = KnowledgeAgentFactory.newKnowledgeAgent(this.config.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.DROOLS_KNOWLEDGE_AGENT_NAME), this.knowledgeAgentConfig);
    Resource resource = ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(this.config.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.DROOLS_BASE_KNOWLEDGE_AGENT_CHANGE_SET_PATH));
    this.knowledgeAgent.applyChangeSet(resource);

}

public StatelessKnowledgeSession getStatelessSession() {
    KnowledgeAgent knowledgeAgent = getKnowledgeAgent();
    return knowledgeAgent.getKnowledgeBase().newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
}

public StatefulKnowledgeSession getStatefullSession() {
    KnowledgeAgent knowledgeAgent = getKnowledgeAgent();
    return knowledgeAgent.getKnowledgeBase().newStatefulKnowledgeSession( );
}
 }
```

We are using  the StatefulKnowledgeSession, `public StatefulKnowledgeSession getStatefullSession()` method. We create a Spring bean of this class and inject at other classes to use drools.

Comment: `waiting to lock <97872c0> (a [Ljava.util.jar.JarFile;)` Did you scramble some information on this or is actual dump output? Is there something special in your configuration? How are you loading the session? Stateless or statefull? Spring integration? Does the issue resolve on its own or do you take some actions such as reboot?

Comment: @JAndy, this is the snippet from the actual dump output, i don't think there is something special in configuration(pasted above), I am pasting the actual configuration in the post itself to have a better clarity. We are using stateful sessions. The threads gets blocked and then we need to reboot.